# Strcpy() Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I have created a function which searches each line of a file and tries to match the parameter `par_string` with a string in the file. I have variants of the function working for doubles and ints, but I can't seem to modify the function to read in strings from file.

Currently I am using `sscanf()` to read in a line and my current effort is to use `strcpy()` to copy the string in the file to the string parameter `parameter` defined in the function argument. However, my function is seg faulting once I reach `strcpy()`, and I can't quite figure out why.

I'm hoping to be able to call the function as `read_string("FILENAME", filename);` in my main function to be able to pass in a parameter to the function and have the filename returned to the variable `filename`. I've tried defining `filename` using

```
char filename[MAXLINE]
```

and

```
char *filename = malloc(sizeof(*filename) * MAXLINE);
```

but both have the same problem.

Below is the function I've written. Is there anything obvious I'm missing or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

```
int 
read_string(char par_string[], char *parameter)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE], ini_par_name[MAX_LINE], par_separator[MAX_LINE];
    char par_value[MAX_LINE];

    FILE *par_file;

    if ((par_file = fopen(INI_FILE, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open parameter file 'plane.ini'.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int linenum = 0;
    parameter = STRING_NO_PAR_CONST;

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, par_file) != NULL)
    {        
        linenum++;

        /* 
        * If the line is a comment, skip that line. Note: There is a bug here
        * which will cause the script to crash if there is a blank line.
        */
        if (line[0] == '#' || line[0] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }

        /* 
        * Check a normal line is in the correct format
        */
        if (sscanf(line, "%s %s %s", ini_par_name, par_separator, par_value) \
            != 3)
        {
            printf("Syntax error, line %d for parameter %s\n", linenum,
                par_string);
            exit(-1);
        }

        /* 
        * Use strcmp to compare the difference between two strings. If it's
        * the same parameter, then strcmp will return 0. 
        */
        if (strcmp(par_string, ini_par_name) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(parameter, par_value);
        }
    }

    /* 
    * If parameter wasn't updated, the parameter was not found. Return an
    * error. 
    */
    if (parameter == STRING_NO_PAR_CONST)
    {
        printf("Parameter %s could not be found.\nExiting simulation.\n",
            par_string);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (fclose(par_file) != 0)
    {
        printf("File could not be closed.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is this line doing?

```
parameter = STRING_NO_PAR_CONST;
```

If it is assigning `parameter` to point to a string literal, that is likely your problem, you cannot modify the contents of a string literal.

If `STRING_NO_PAR_CONST` is `'\0'`, that is just a `char`, not a `string`.  As long as `parameter` has correctly been allocated some memory prior to calling `read_string()`, you can just

```
parameter[0] = STRING_NO_PAR_CONST
```

and the same when you check to see if it has changed

```
if (parameter[0] == STRING_NO_PAR_CONST)
```

Comment: ah, I see. `STRING_NO_PAR_CONST = '\0'`. I was using something similar in another function as a check to see if the variable was found. It fixed my issue though, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

A few things

strcpy is called as the following -> strcpy(destination, source). You are using parameter as the destination.

That being said, the amount of space you allocate should be the maximum size of the string you want. I don't think that it should equal the maximum number of lines in a given file (though I could be wrong)